# Referencing field default to another field in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have mongoengine model, and I want to reference some field of that model as another's default. Theoretically, it may look like this:

```
class User(Document):
    first_name = StringField(default=lambda: self.full_name['first'])
    full_name = DictField()
```

For saving docs, I can alter the `.save()` method, but I want it to work at retrieval too. I.e.:

```
User(full_name{'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe').save()
u = User.objects().first().first_name()
>>> John
```

Is it possible in some way in current mongoengine?

PS: yes, I know that such schema leads to denormalization.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can reference the "self" in the default value of a field, and if you could, it would probably be the Field instance, not your Document.

To have the behaviour you have defined, I would define a good old property and a protected field.

```
class User(Document):
    _first_name = StringField()
    full_name = DictField(required=True)

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self._first_name or self.full_name.get('first')

    @first_name.setter
    def first_name(self, value):
       self._first_name = value
```

This way, you would have :

```
user = User()
user.first_name
>>> None
user.full_name = {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe'}
>>> John
user.save()
user = User.objects().first()
user.first_name
>>> John
user.first_name = 'Jake'
user.first_name
>>> Jake
user.full_name.get('first')
>>> John
```